# Passing batches to Tensorflow Structural Time Seires

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-probability

I am creating a model for time series prediction with Tensorflow Probability, following [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/examples/Structural_Time_Series_Modeling_Case_Studies_Atmospheric_CO2_and_Electricity_Demand#data). In these examples I need to pass all data at once, but this is prohibitive when dealing with big data (my case), how should I pass batches or any other kind of lazy loaded data to this tool?

Comment: Not sure about tensorflow probability, but for tensorflow keras we have methods like train_on_batch where you can just give a single batch at a time.

Comment: Thanks, it's really easy and well documented for tensorflow keras and tensorflow custom training loops, but is not for tfp.

Answer (score 1):

This is a general problem for most probabilistic inference cases: using most non-full-batch gradients will yield biased samples.

You should be able to write a `target_log_prob_fn` with a `tf.custom_gradient` to iterate over a `tf.data.Dataset` iterator. Since the target logprob is a scalar, you can accumulate both gradients and logprobs as the function proceeds over all minibatches in the dataset.

```
ds = build_dataset()
def build_model(params):
  return time_series_model(..)

@tf.custom_gradient
@tf.function  # autograph should turn the dataset loop into a tf.while_loop.
def log_prob(*params):
  total_lp = 0.
  total_grad = tf.nest.map_structure(tf.zeros_like, params)
  for batch in ds:
    lp, grad = tfp.math.value_and_gradient(
        lambda *p: build_model(p).log_prob(batch),
        params)
    total_lp += lp
    total_grad = tf.nest.map_structure(lambda x,y: x+y, total_grad, grad)
  return total_lp, lambda dy: tf.nest.map_structure(lambda g: dy*g, total_grad)
```

Comment: can you give me some references? I would like understand what are the `params`, and what funciton must return.